# How to prevent GCP Cloud Shell from automatic popping up in console every time I open a page

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Some time ago (a month or more) GCP Cloud Shell started to show up automatically every time I opened a page (some GCP page). It says it's reconnecting to the existing service. It happens even if I close the one on my first page. Then when I open a new page (for example, with Ctrl + Mouse Left Click in windows in Chrome) the Cloud shell automatically opens up again.

I would like Cloud Shell on the new page to be open only if I manually open it. Maybe I need to configure something somewhere. It's also bad because it uses the available quota for Cloud Shell, decreasing it without my will.

How is it possible to achieve that and disable auto-opening of GCP Cloud Shell?

Comment: Do you have `&cloudshell=true` in the URL you use to access the cloud console? if yes, remove that!

Comment: Yes indeed. But it's a part of ALL links on any pages. is it possible to remove it from links by default?

Comment: when you open `cloudshell` it is appended with `true`. and when you close it, its value becomes `false`. if you have issues with that then most probably it's something with your browser. anyway, remove this part when you first hit the console and everything should be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the URL in your browser. most probably you will find `&cloudshell=true` appended to it. remove that part and you should be fine.

---

Note:

When you open `cloudshell`. the mentioned part is appended with the value `true`. and when you close it, its value becomes `false`. if you have issues with that then most probably it's something with your browser.